# Parenthesis around placement new operator for arrays

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, placement-new, internal-compiler-error

Playing around with placement new for arrays, I came up (by chance/mistake) with the following code:

```
#include <new>

struct X{};

int main()
{
    char buf[256];
    std::size_t n = 10;
    X* p = new (buf) (X[n]); // incorrect way, parenthesis by mistake
    //X* p = new (buf) X[n]; // correct way
}
```

The third line in `main` is incorrect, although it compiles. There shouldn't be any parenthesis. [clang++ spits out](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6f14b0a179d2451)

> warning: when type is in parentheses, array cannot have dynamic size

while gcc6 outputs

> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array [-Wvla]
>        X* p = new (buf) (X[n]);
>
> warning: non-constant array new length must be specified without parentheses around the type-id [-Wvla]
>        X* p = new (buf) (X[n]);

then [crashes with an internal compiler error (ICE)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85836966edd346cd) in *tree_to_uhwi, at tree.h:4044*. The internal compiler error appears only in gcc >= 6.

**My question:** how exactly is the line marked "incorrect" parsed/interpreted, why is it "wrong" to have those parentheses?*

<sup>*For the ICE, I'll fill out a bug anyway.</sup>

**EDIT 1** I just realized that the ICE/warning(s) have nothing to do with user defined types, so the same behaviour is observed for `int` instead of `struct X`.

**EDIT 2** gcc6 bug filled [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77804). The ICE does not appear in gcc5 or earlier versions (only the warnings appear, which are correct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the parentheses, the type to be newed comes from a *type-id*, in this case `X[n]`.  This is a variable length array which is not standard behavior.  Without the parentheses, the type to be newed is a *new-type-id*, an array of `X`.

Comment: If it is the case, new(buf)(X) and new (buf)X are the same? Thanks

Comment: @KenmanTsang Yes, if my reading of the standard language is right.

Comment: @Nik-Lz _type-id_ and _new-type-id_ are from the language specification.  You can see what they are [on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Type_naming).